# Проверка пароля на ZIP архиве

Tags: python, файлы, zip

Пишу утилиту для работы и требуется проверять zip архив на наличие пароля. Если пароль имеется - обрабатывать файл одними правилами, если нет - упаковывать и обрабатывать другими.

Подскажите, как лучше проверять архив на наличие пароля? Есть ли возможность делать это без распаковки? Возможно есть какой либо пакет для обработки?

Спасибо!

Comment: Если коротко, вам надо получить объект типа `ZipInfo` и проверить его `flag_bits` по маске `0x1`. Т.е. выставленный первый бит - признак наличия шифрования.

Comment: @user207200 ну уж дали бы ссылку уже https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038446/how-to-check-if-a-zip-file-is-encrypted-using-pythons-standard-library-zipfile

Comment: @strawdog откуда мне знать об этом вопросе.